# Mounting a local file to a specific path in the container of ActiveMQ Artemis, container stops working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jboss, activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

The image I am using is `quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker`.

My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, the container can successfully run.

I then go inside the container (container id `5905b9`):

```
~ docker exec -it 5905b9 bash
[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ pwd
/home/jboss
```

I can see that the default path right after get in is `/home/jboss`.

I also verified that there is `/home/jboss/broker/etc/` directory inside the container (by default):

```
[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ pwd
/home/jboss

[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ ls
broker

[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ ls ./broker/etc/
artemis-roles.properties  artemis.profile  bootstrap.xml  jolokia-access.xml  login.config
artemis-users.properties           broker.xml     log4j2.properties   management.xml
```

I also verified that there is `/home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis` file inside container:

```
[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ ls ./broker/bin/
artemis  artemis-service
```

(Please keep above verification in mind, it relates to the failure log below)

**After verified these things.** I stoped the container by `docker-compose down`.

Then, I modified my `docker-compose.yml` to **mount** a local file on my host `./config/my.json` **to** the container path `/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password

    # mount local file to container path
    volumes:
      - ./config/my.json:/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Then, I run the `docker-compose up` again . However, this time, the container starting failed. The log shows this message:

```
2024-03-03 18:51:40 /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh: line 49: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis: No such file or directory
2024-03-03 18:51:40 Running Broker
```

The logs basically says the `launch.sh` tries to access file `/home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis` but there isn't such file. But like I verified above, this file DOES exists!

**Why** after modified `docker-compose.yml` to mount my local file to that specific container path, the ActiveMQ Artemis container stopped working & throw that weird message??

**====More debugging info====**

I also noticed if I change the mount path to :

```
volumes:
  - ./config/my.json:/home/jboss/my.json
```

Then the container can run successfully, I can see `my.json` in that container path:

```
[jboss@6af16611b85e ~]$ ls
broker my.json
```

But I need to have it inside `/home/jboss/broker/etc/`.

**====== update to run container with root user ====**

Thanks for the answer from @Domenico Francesco Bruscino, I tried to run the container with root user:

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    user: "root"
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true

    
    volumes:
      # mount local file to container path as a new file works well!
      - ./config/my.json:/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json

      # mount local file to overwrite a file in container path fails!
      - ./config/login.config:/home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Mounting local file as a new file in the container path `/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json` works well!

But mounting local file that overwrite an existing file in the same path fails with error:

```
2024-03-04 22:30:59 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: broker/etc/login.config (Permission denied)
```

Comment: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis:./config/my.json

which one is your dockers and host
make sure host:docker

Comment: @BeteGoshme, I hope I understand you right. But your comment doesn't look correct. Because I think the left hand side path is the one from the host & the right side of the colon is the path inside container. That's why I use `./config/my.json:/home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis`, where `./config/my.json` is the host path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `launch.sh` script of `quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker` container image doesn't create a broker instance when the `broker` directory already exist, see https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-image/blob/1.0.25/modules/activemq-artemis-install/added/launch.sh#L17

You need to run the container with the root user and to set the enviornment variable `AMQ_RESET_CONFIG` to `true` to force artemis to create a broker instance when the `broker` directory already exist, i.e.

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    user: "root"
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true

    # mount local file to container path
    volumes:
      - ./config/my.json:/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Alternatively, you could pass a full broker instance when you need to add custom files to the `/home/jboss/broker` directory.

To avoid to run the container with the root user you can overwrite the container command, i.e.

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true

    # mount local file to container path
    volumes:
      - ./config/my.json:/config/my.json
    command: bash -c 'mkdir -p /home/jboss/broker/etc && cp /config/my.json /home/jboss/broker/etc/ && /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh'

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it when I am on my computer. BTW, will `MQ_RESET_CONFIG: true` allow both new files be added and overwrite the content of `broker/login.config` in the default `broker` directory? I mean I'd like to overwrite & add some files in the default `broker/` directory but keep all the other files there as they are.

Comment: I also don't understand your explanation that the `launch.sh` doesn't create broker instance when `broker/` directory already exists. The `broker/` directory does exist when I didn't have volume mounted and container was running well, in other words, broker instance was created successfully while having the default `broker/` directory. Only after I added the volume mount the issue come... if you get what I mean.

Comment: After I added `AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: "true"` and run the container, there is a new error  `The path 'broker' is not writable.`

Comment: You are getting the error `The path 'broker' is not writable` because docker compose mount the volumes with the root user. You can fix this issue running the container with the root user or overwriting the container command. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I used the root user way from your updated answer. Now I can mount a new file into the `/home/jboss/broker/etc/` directory inside container successfully.  But I also would like to overwrite the file `/home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config`,  with the root user way, I tried the volumes `- ./config/login.config:/home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config`, when start the container, it raise error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: broker/etc/login.config (Permission denied)`... how to get rid of this?

Comment: I updated my post with the outcome when running with root user, if you could take a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user842225 the original question was related to mount additional files. Could you approve my answer if it answers your original question and create another question to overwrite files created by the artemis create command? I'll be happy to provide some solutions to the eventual new question.

Comment: sure thing! I will create a new post for the overwriting issue after my work & ping you. Thanks!

Comment: here is my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78107665/mounting-a-local-file-to-overwrite-a-default-file-in-the-container-of-activemq-a

Comment: @user842225 thanks, I have just answered with some solutions to the new question