# Mounting a local file to overwrite a default file in the container of ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jboss, activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

The image I am using is `quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker`.

In my `docker-compose.yml`, I run the container with root user:

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    user: "root"
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true

    
    volumes:
      # mount local file to container path as a new file works well!
      - ./config/my.json:/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json

      # mount local file to overwrite a file in container path fails!
      - ./config/login.config:/home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Mounting local file as a new file in the container path `/home/jboss/broker/etc/my.json` works well!

But mounting local file to overwrite an existing file in the same path fails with error:

```
2024-03-04 22:30:59 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: broker/etc/login.config (Permission denied)
```

**What I have verified:**

I have verified that there is `/home/jboss/broker/etc/` directory inside the container (by default) and inside the path there is `login.config` file which I try to overwrite:

```
[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ pwd
/home/jboss

[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ ls
broker

[jboss@5905b996368e ~]$ ls ./broker/etc/
...  login.config
...
```

So, how can I mount my local file `./config/login.config` on host to overwrite the file in container path `/home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config`??

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works only for `loging.config` is to point the broker to a custom `loging.config` path by setting the system property `ava.security.auth.login.config`, i.e.

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    user: "root"
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password
      JAVA_ARGS_APPEND: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/amq/login.config"

    
    volumes:
      # mount local file to overwrite a file in container path fails!
      - ./config/login.config:/opt/amq/login.config

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

A more generic solution requires to overwrite the container command, i.e.

```
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    user: "root"
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: password

    
    volumes:
      # mount local file to overwrite a file in container path fails!
      - ./config/login.config:/opt/amq/etc/login.config

    command: bash -c "sed 's~  configure~  configure\n  cp --recursive /opt/amq/etc/* /home/jboss/broker/etc~' /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh | source /dev/stdin"

    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Alternatively, you could pass a full broker instance when you need to overwrite instance files in the the /home/jboss/broker directory.